# With a jupyter notebook running an R kernel in vscode, how do you run a cell in debug mode?

Tags: python, r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am running a jupyter notebook that is running an R kernel allowing me to run R code in the notebook. I used this article to install and setup the R kernel for jupyter notebooks [run R code in a jupyter notebook](https://www.datacamp.com/blog/jupyter-and-r-markdown-notebooks-with-r).

Everything runs great, however, I am unable to run cells in debug mode. When I run a jupyter notebook with a python kernel, the debug mode works fine. But the debug option is not available for R.

***Jupyter Notebook with Python Kernel***
[image: Jupyter Notebook with Python Kernel]

***Jupyter Notebook with R Kernel***
[image: Jupyter Notebook with R Kernel]

Is there a way to run jupyter notebooks with an R kernel in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

The R debugging capabilities are provided by [R Debugger extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RDebugger.r-debugger).

Jupyter-notebook currently does not support this feature. I have made [a request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/14216) to the developers in Github for you.

You can debug R language without jupyter according to [this document](https://github.com/ManuelHentschel/VSCode-R-Debugger) to solve your problem.

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you for putting in the request. I guess for now I'll use the vscode-r-debugger extension.